# Query table column based on another tables column value for user settings?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this or not, but I have `jobs` table that a user can search from on my website. I want to save the users filter settings in another table called `filter_prefs`.
The only way I can perceive to do this is, when a user looks for jobs, I have to select the categories of jobs depending on which category is selected and query the database for the jobs. Thus when a user "un selects" a check box it removes the listings, but not the checkbox. Simultaneously I store that as a `0` in that `filter_pref` category column so that if the user comes back and loads the jobs, the checkbox will be loaded on the website, but unchecked, thus not triggering the query for that category in jobs.

```
      jobs                            filter_prefs
+-----+-----+----------+------+      +-----+------------+---------+--------+
| jid | pay | category | Title       | uid | Contractor | Teacher | Driver |
+-----+-----+----------+------+      +-----+------------+---------+--------+
|  5  | 15  |Contractor|Roofer|      |  4  |     0      |    1    |    1   |
|  6  | 20  |  Teacher |  Bio |      +-----+------------+---------+--------+
|  7  | 18  |  Driver  |  LTL |
+-----+-----+----------+------+
```

The issue I am running into is, when I query the categories from the table, I need to query the `filter_prefs` table for the exact column that was queried in the first `fetch` loop of the statement which forces me to concatenate the query string for the column. I keep reading how this is MySQL suicide.  **is this ok?**

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT category FROM jobs WHERE status='o'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($category);
    while($stmt->fetch()){

$sql="SELECT '.$category.' FROM filter_prefs WHERE uid=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['uid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($status);
$product_cat ='';
    while($stmt->fetch()){
if($status==1){
$product_cat .= // MARK CHECKED, $CATEGORY AS TITLE.

}if($status==0){
$product_cat .= // MARK UNCHECKED, $CATEGORY AS TITLE.
}
}
}
echo $product_cat;
```

I am really new to MySQL and PHP so I just cant perceive a different way of doing it. Is there a better way to store user preferences, pull them out, then influence the state of the website? I couldnt find any material out there that showed how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT '.$category.'` < that won't work. Single quotes should not be used here, you're passing a string literal.

Comment: This post does not contain a clear expression in one statement of either your DBMS error or your goal. And you are not asking 1 clear question. Which would be that clear statement. When clear this will be a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter_prefs` should be

```
   uid jid
   4   6
   4   7
```

That way a user's jobs are:

```
SELECT uid, category
FROM filter_prefs
JOIN jobs
 USING jid
```

Keep the data structure logical so that its easy to query and make the php presentation layer accommodate the presentation.

If you are pulling out a field from a row and trying to map this to a different table name you've done something wrong.

Comment: i honestly dont understand why the table filter_prefs should be structured like that. each job has a category and there could be multiple jobs with the same category. why would i want to associate a jid with a uid if there are 10000 users and 3000 jobs? please clarify!

Comment: The `jid` in `filter_prefs` would be a job category. `jobs` looked like a category map in your question. So I expect for each user there is only a minimal set of categories. This way adding more categories doesn't require altering the table.

Comment: the jobs table is supposed to be everything related to the job, such as location, pay, title, position, everything. I just tried to simplify it as much as i could. each job has a category, which is why i am `SELECT DISTINCT` because they could be duplicates. what should i do in this case?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` over an entire large table as you stated to get categories is a waste. Create your own job categories table with a simple `job_category_id`. Use that to populate the checkboxes, and `JOIn` on this table to fill out a list of job information for a user.

Comment: ok, but i believe, then based on the way i do it, it will select every single category there is, and echo every category out, putting category boxes checked and unchecked even if there are no jobs listed with those categories.